# Problems Certificate for <fyber.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names:

Tags: gradle

good evening I have a problem with my code I get this error

Certificate for <fyber.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.jfrog.io, *.int.jfrog.io, jfrog.io, *.pe.jfrog.io]

build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/' }


    }
    dependencies {
        // class
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:4.10.0"



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

help me please

help me please
help me solve this error please I've been trying for more than 1 week